# what is difference between view and page flow logic

Tags: sap-bsp

I am new in sap.I read the documentation of BSP, i understand controller,view and model,like in java. But i am confused in `page flow logic`.I have few questions.

1). what is this and what is difference b/w `view` and `page flow logic`.
2). what code should i write in `view` and `page flow logic`.
3). what is use of `page flow logic`. Is BSP has four part, model, controller,view and page flow logic.

Answer (score 0):

Page Flow Logic is for your index.html page. The view folder contains your views and controllers.

Comment: where to write model, in function module or inBSP class??